# Trying to fill Hexagon shape with color

Tags: vb.net, hexagonal-tiles

I'm drawing a 2d grid of hexagons using the DrawPolygon function.  Works great, but I'm trying to figure out how to fill them with a certain color.  It would appear the FillEllipse function is only meant for rectangles.  Is there something I could use to fill shapes made with DrawPolygon?  Please note, the below code includes a function I'm too lazy to include called CreateHex, which passes 2 coordinates (x and y of course) which it uses to calculate the 6 points which CreateHex uses to return the 6 points needed for the Hexagon.  Here's my code:

```
    Dim myPen As New Pen(Color.Black)
    Dim PicGraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
    Dim DrawFont As New Font("Arial", SizeSide / 3)
    Dim drawFormat As New StringFormat
    Dim drawBrush As New SolidBrush(Color.Black)
    For lc = 1 To ColNum
        For lc2 = 1 To RowNum
            PicGraphics.DrawPolygon(myPen, CreateHex(lc, lc2))
            PicGraphics.FillEllipse(New SolidBrush(Color.Red), CreateHex(lc, lc2)) ' <---- this doesn't work.
        Next
    Next
```

If I comment out the FillEllipse statement, it draws the polygons normally.  But if its uncommented, it will draw nothing at all.  Anyone know of a solution?

Comment: [Graphics.FillPolygon Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fillpolygon(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Works perfectly.  Man I need to stop smoking weed...  :(

Comment: Might help with the laziness issue too. Also your code is leaking

Comment: My code is leaking?

Comment: You're creating fonts, brushes, and pens and not disposing of them.  Eventually you may run out of GDI resources.

Comment: ah thanks!  I will dispose of them appropriately.